# Reading 64 bit integers binary file

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++

I am asking for the correct way to read a binary files by taking blocks that are 64 bits of size. I am currently doing it this way :

```
    uint64_t uInt;
    char c;
    if(istr)
  {
    while (true)
    {
        istr.get(c);
        if (istr.eof())
            break;
        istr.putback(c);
        istr.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&uInt), sizeof(uInt));
        tea.encryptBlock(uInt, ostr);
    }
  }
```

istr and ostr are streams to files I want to read/write to. While it works for the biggest part of the file while debugging I used binary viewer and it seems like that the last 32 bits are wrong(i need them because i am trying to do encryption/decryption using the tiny encryption algorithm which uses 64 bit block split into 2 halves). I am not sure what is causing this problem and I was thinking that maybe I should try to read only characters and then combine them using something like this:

```
  int64_t charTo64bitNum(char *a) {
  int64_t n = 0;
  n = (((int64_t)a[0] << 56) & 0xFF00000000000000U)
    | (((int64_t)a[1] << 48) & 0x00FF000000000000U)
    | (((int64_t)a[2] << 40) & 0x0000FF0000000000U)
    | (((int64_t)a[3] << 32) & 0x000000FF00000000U)
    | ((a[4] << 24) & 0x00000000FF000000U)
    | ((a[5] << 16) & 0x0000000000FF0000U)
    | ((a[6] << 8) & 0x000000000000FF00U)
    | (a[7] & 0x00000000000000FFU);
    return n;
 }
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: And your file size is a multiple of 64 bits? BTW: you open the file in binary mode, are you?

Comment: Probably easier to read in 32bit chunks and combine pairs of them in code.  That way you won't be left trying to read the last 32bits into 64bits

Comment: Is it big-endian or little-endian data?  Are you using a big-endian or little-endian processor?  If the endianness doesn't match, you'll need to byte-swap things around.

Comment: @ChrisDodd the endianness is not the problem here

Comment: @StephanLechner I do open it in binary mode and the test file is a multiple

Answer (score 0):

Try to read a chunk of 8 bytes from your file to `uint8_t buff[8]`, and then do

```
   uint8_t buff[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
   uint64_t val = (uint64_t)buff[7] 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[6] << 8) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[5] << 16) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[4] << 24) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[3] << 32) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[2] << 40) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[1] << 48) 
                  | ((uint64_t)buff[0] << 56);
  // buff == 0x0001020304050607LL
  // to split:
  uint32_t val1 = (uint32_t)(val & ((1 << 32) - 1));
  uint32_t val2 = (uint32_t)(val >> 32);
```

Update: reversed indices

```
//[0]83 [1]111 [2]109 [3]101 [4]32 [5]116 [6]101 [7]120
uint8_t arr[] = { 83, 111, 109, 101, 32, 116, 101, 120 };
uint64_t expected = 8675467939688574803;
uint64_t val = (uint64_t)arr[0] 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[1] << 8) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[2] << 16) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[3] << 24) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[4] << 32) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[5] << 40) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[6] << 48) 
    | ((uint64_t)arr[7] << 56);
```

Comment: Tried it, the buffer did fill up with the correct values(at least at the start where I checked) but the 64 bit value i got didn't seem to be correct. I could try to just get 32bits because in the end I split up the value,but I am not sure if that is the problem

Comment: I don't understand what it means "didn't seem to be correct". a) What's in your buffer b) what do you expect c) what you've got

Comment: The buffer is fine I read everything as it is in the file. Then i obtain the uint64_t val as u have said. When i split it i get 2 32 bit integers. I then open the file in binary viewer where i can see those 2 32 bit integers. They are not the same. Hope this makes it clearer to what I mean

Comment: I need one uint8_t[8] value in your buffer and two uint64_t values - expected and actual.

Comment: [0]83 [1]111 [2]109 [3]101 [4]32 [5]116 [6]101 [7]120  is the buffer ,expected  - 8675467939688574803
, val - 6012144308666525048

Comment: Expected value has byte order 01234567, actual has byte order 76543210. You should just reverse indices in my code. is that so hard?